# How to disable the ability to change shipping method on the checkout page in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, shipping-method

I would like to disable the ability to change shipping method on the **Checkout page** in WooCommerce. The user selects the shipping method on the **Cart page** and I do not want to let them change it on the **Checkout page.**

I'm looking for some `filter` that can be used there. What I found is `woocommerce_cart_ready_to_calc_shipping` but it completely hides it.

*Note: I would not like to overwrite the template file so I am looking for an way with a `filter` or `action`*